# Calibrating ESC and then using it

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, motor, servo

i have 30Amp ESC which i can move motor by providing values ,

but i am unable to know what is the minimum and maximum throttle speed of the motor....

how to achieve that level of info through arduino,

although when i calibrate through Open pilot software ,it is able to calibrate and the minimum value is 1500ms ..

Also after calibrating it once , do i need to arm everytime before using ESC in the arduino program through serial input ?

Comment: What values? How do you provide them? What ESC? What everything basically...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this code -

```
/*
Coded by Marjan Olesch
Sketch from Insctructables.com
Open source - do what you want with this code!
*/
#include <Servo.h>


int value = 0; // set values you need to zero

Servo firstESC, secondESC; //Create as much as Servoobject you want. You can controll 2 or more Servos at the same time

void setup() {

  firstESC.attach(9);    // attached to pin 9 I just do this with 1 Servo
  Serial.begin(9600);    // start serial at 9600 baud

}

void loop() {

//First connect your ESC WITHOUT Arming. Then Open Serial and follo Instructions

  firstESC.writeMicroseconds(value);

  if(Serial.available()) 
    value = Serial.parseInt();    // Parse an Integer from Serial

}
```

the problem was when i was connecting the battery , it was not making any sounds...it was already calibrated by open pilot GCS so it was not calibrating again... i needed to reset the ESC and then run this program from arduino

Comment: If this sketch solved you problem, you should accept the answer; If you tried this and are still stuck, it should put in an edit to your question.